# Publish artifact to local maven repo with SBT and use it in Gradle project

Tags: java, scala, maven, gradle, sbt

Here is what I want to do:

- In my Scala sbt project, I want to publish an artifact to my **local** maven repository
- Afterwards, I want to use this artifact in a Gradle-based Java project

Here is where I struggle:

- I have published the artifact somewhat successful using `sbt publishM2`. Here is my `build.sbt`:

```scala
organization := "com.example"
name := "my.messaging"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
publishMavenStyle := true
```

This generates the artifact here:

`C:\Users\BAIERLF\.m2\repository\com\example\my-messaging_2.12\0.1`

The POM  file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-messaging_2.12</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>my.messaging</description>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>my.messaging</name>
    <organization>
        <name>com.example</name>
    </organization>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ArtimaMavenRepository</id>
            <name>Artima Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.artima.com/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I find myself unable to successfully use this artifact in my Gradle project. This is how I tried to link it:

```
dependencies {
   compile group: 'com.example', name: 'my-messaging_2.12', version: '0.1'
}
```

I feel like I am doing multiple things wrong here, but if anyone could give me a hint that would be great.

**Edit:** I tried it again with a slightly different result, so I updated my answer.

Comment: Did you tried with [`publishLocal`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html#Publishing+Locally)? It had worked for me before... However it had always been **SBT** to **SBT** not sure if it will work with **Gradle**.

Comment: Yes, `publishLocal` publishes it to `.ivy2`, but I need to use it with Maven in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently, and solved it by adding a `mavenLocal()` command to my build.gradle file. I don'y know if you have the same issue, but it might be worth doing a build of your gradle project with full debug output and confirm it's attempting to pull from your local repo.

Comment: Adding `repositories { mavenLocal() }` did the trick for me. Thank you :)